# IIS 7 Wordpress URL Redirect

Tags: wordpress, iis, iis-7, redirect

So I have a site.com/blog/12/12/articleNames and i want to redirect everything to site.com/articles/12/12/articleNames instead.

so in my blog folder i have this in my web.config

```
    <rewrite>

        <rules>
            <rule name="articleMove" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^blog/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([_0-9a-z-])/" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="/articles/{R:1}/{R:2}/{R:3}" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

However, i still keep getting the 404 page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use IIS [Failed Request Tracing](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/467/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules/) to further investigate what is happening "behind the scenes".

Answer (score 1):

```
 <rule name="articleMove" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([_0-9a-z-]+)" />
                    <action type="Redirect" url="/articles/{R:1}/{R:2}/{R:3}" />
                    <conditions>
                    </conditions>
                </rule>
```

So if the URL is http://site.com/blog/whatevergoeshere. Ignore the blog part. and each split you just do {R:1} etc.. so if the url was http://site.com/blog/12/10/the-article-name and you want it to be http://site.com/articles/12/10/the-article-name is what the above does.